# PHP use namespace - A solution to including all classes under a namespace

Tags: php, laravel, namespaces, php-7

Is there a solution to having to include all classes individually under a namespace?

My Laravel files are getting huge because I have to keep including a heck load of namespaces... It's pretty awful!

**As a temporary solution, why might the following not be working:**

namespace.Blah.txt:

```
use Blah\Blah; 
use Blah\Bloh;
```

php code:

```
eval( file_get_contents( "namespace.Blah.txt" );
```

If I could get this to work, I could evaluate the contents of a file... I do understand it's a bit noob... but... dammit!

Comment: As in autoload all classes with a specific namespace?

Comment: How many included classes are we talking about?

Comment: I have about 20 classes at the moment. I pretty much have to include all of them in every controller... I'm really not that fussed about declaring memory for the classes as they are TINY... and they are never auto instantiated so will never be filled. This just isn't a problem for me at this moment in time... If it becomes one, I will go back to the old way... But I'm not understanding why the `eval()` is not working?

Answer (score 7):

There isn't, but in PHP 7 you'll be able to

```
use FooLibrary\Bar\Baz\{ ClassA, ClassB, ClassC, ClassD as Fizbo };
```

As the following RFC has passed:

https://wiki.php.net/rfc/group_use_declarations

EDIT:

Note that too many uses in a class may be a sign of "smell". Isn't that particular class doing too much? Shouldn't you be creating new "base" classes and extending them?

Comment: Thanks for that, I wondered if you might then know if I can do the above (eval)... I know it's horrid... But i'm desperate! And it can be changed at some point if it gets to be noob!

Comment: Too many uses in a class may be a sign of "smell". Isn't that particular class doing too much? Shouldn't you be creating new "base" classes and extending them?

Comment: I'm pretty sure eval will not work in this case, because uses are processed by the compiler. It's only a hint for the compiler to know where to find the class, so if you execute the use from elsewhere it will not work on your current class.

Comment: Hah. Thanks for the tip man. Any ideas why you can't evaluate the use keyword?

Comment: Because it's not really for evaluation, it's just a hint. You can replace `use Foo; Foo::whatever()` by `\Foo::whatever();`, so it's something only to tell PHP where to find that class.

Comment: Thanks for your input Antonio. Starting to think that the only "option" is to create a first pass php file that you run before production... that runs over all the php files and finds where you have called a specific function... It then re-creates all the php files specified by that function and inserts the use namespaces into the php file. I've given you an upvote for your troubles man. Thanks once again.

Comment: As I've said, you may be doing too much in those classes to need something like this. If you need A, B and C in a class you better create another class, D, wich uses A, B and C and the create your class using only D. So you might have to think a little about application design before doing something like you said, pre-processing all of your files to insert uses...